# Inyección ManagedBean fuera del ciclo de vida de JSF

Tags: web, mongodb, jsf, java-ee, nosql

Me gustaría saber si el enfoque que estoy siguiendo es el correcto y en dicho caso como solventar la siguiente causistica.

Tengo un ManagedBean de ambito Application para el acceso distribuido de las conexiones NOSQL con la BD y un DAO que se encarga de administrar las conexiones y su mantenimiento( aqui se inyecta el bean @ManagedProperty).

El problema surge al llamar al dao para obtener la conexión NOSQL, al realizar un new(...) el bean no se inicializa ya que necesita ser inicializado dentro del ciclo de vida de JSF.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class FactoriaMongoDAO extends FactoriaDAO {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{mongoConnector.client}")
    MongoClient mongoClient;
```

```
public class xx{
 FactoriaDAO.getInstancia().getPatientPlayerDAO();
}
```

```
@ManagedBean
public abstract class FactoriaDAO {
  private static FactoriaDAO unicainstancia = null;

    public FactoriaDAO(){}

    public static FactoriaDAO getInstancia() {
        if (unicainstancia == null) unicainstancia = new FactoriaMongoDAO( "xx");
        return unicainstancia;
    }  
        public abstract PatientPlayerDAO getPatientPlayerDAO();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ManagedProperty solo es posible de inyectar en beans administrados(@ManagedBean).

La solucion es recurrir al contexto del servlet:

Bean bean = (Bean) getServletContext().getAttribute("beanName");